# value referred by pointer used to intialize reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, output, expression

well i have a trivial doubt in following statement

```
int a = 5;
int* ptr = &a; 
int &x = *ptr;
x = 3;
cout<<a;
```

output is 3;
`*ptr` passes a dereferenced integer vaue to the reference reference`&x` but howcome changing `x` changes `a`?. `*ptr` just throws an intger no address of where it pointing.How come compiler binds `x` to `a's` address??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this declaration

```
int* ptr = &a;
```

the pointer ptr points to the object a.

Dereferencing the pointer

int &x = *ptr;

yields an lvalue reference to the original object a,

So x now is an lvalue reference to the object a.

The effect is the same as if initially you would write

```
int &x = a;
```

From the C++ Standard (5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 1 The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which
>   it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a
>   function type and the **result is an lvalue referring to the object or
>   function** to which the expression points.

Answer (score 1):

> but howcome changing x changes a?

You cannot "change" references. When you assign to `x`, the object referred by `x` is assigned. `x` refers to `a`, so assignment of `x` is assignment of `a`.

> How come compiler binds x to a's address??

Given that pointer `ptr` points to `a`, indirection through the pointer `*ptr` yields an lvalue that refers to `a`. As such, if you initialise the reference `x` with such expression, the reference will be bound to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

There's this nice feature you could do with C++.

Have you ever tried this before?

```
void somefunction(int &foo) {
     foo = 3;
}
```

And when you used that function like this:

```
int a = 5;
somefunction(a);
// From now on, a = 3
```

a will change its value to 3.

Same here in your code, you dereferenced the value but at the same time you're passing a to x.

It's pretty useful when you're passing objects. And you don't want to do something like this `somefunction(&a)`. It makes your code cleaner that way.

---

Sorry, I'm on mobile and I don't know how to format yet posts.